# Selecting row by field and exact list of join id

Tags: mysql, join, select

I have 2 tables. For simplicity, first table `Parent` contains only `id` and `name`. Other table `Child` contains `id` and `parent_id`.

There are going to be many parent rows with the same name. They will have different childrens, so I want to be able to select a parent row only if it has childs from the list I provide.

Let's say I want a Parent with name 'test' only if it has Childs with id (223, 224, 225).

So far I achieved this with following query:

```
SELECT p.*, GROUP_CONCAT(c.id) as childs
FROM `parent` p
    INNER JOIN `child` c ON p.id = c.parent_id
WHERE p.name = 'test'
GROUP BY p.name
HAVING childs = '223,224,225'
ORDER BY c.id
```

However I think it's not a good solution if it uses id concatenation

Comment: What is exactly the question? Could you please add a sample data and a desired result?

Comment: You need `ORDER BY c.id` inside the `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply *conditional aggregation*

```
HAVING sum(case when c.id in (223,224,225) then 1 else -1 end) = 3
```

This assumes that those ids are unique.